# regex with mongolite in R

Tags: r, mongodb, mongolite

Trying to do a regex match with the awesome mongolite library and I am still not sure what I am doing wrong, going really nuts on what am i missing here.

```
library(mongolite)
m <- mongo(url = "mongodb://192.168.1.5:27017", db = "products", collection =    "sku")

m$count()
#gives 54524

a1 <- m$find('{"item"  : { "$regex" : "/.*A*./i" }}')
returns Imported 0 records. Simplifying into dataframe...

#but when you do
a1 <- m$find('{"item"  : "ABC"}')
#returns 8 records
a1 <- m$find('{"item"  : "AAC"}')
#returns 5 records
a1 <- m$find('{"item"  : "AAAC"}')
#returns 18 records
```

so on. So I am not sure what is wrong in the way I am calling the regex operator in mongodb. Any clues.? Thanks

Comment: Does your regex query work in the mongo shell?

Comment: try `a1 <- m$find('{ "item" : { "$regex" : ".*A*." , "$options" : "i"} }')`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the mongo shell you would use the `/ ... /` without quotes. However, within `mongolite` you need the quotes otherwise it's **invalid JSON**

You therefore need to use `... { "$regex" : ".*A*.", "$options" : "i"}...`

Consider this example

```
library(mongolite)

m <- mongo(db = "test", collection = "test", url = "mongodb://localhost")

## create and insert some dummy data
set.seed(2016)
df <- data.frame(id = seq(1:100),
                val = sample(letters, size = 100, replace = T))

m$insert(df)

## valid regex query in mongolite
m$find('{ "val" : { "$regex" : "^a", "$options" : "i" }  }')
# Imported 5 records. Simplifying into dataframe...
#     id val
# 1  26   a
# 2  53   a
# 3  61   a
# 4  76   a
# 5 100   a

## these queries don't work. 
m$find('{ "val" : { "$regex" : "/^a/", "$options" : "i" }  }')
# Imported 0 records. Simplifying into dataframe...
# data frame with 0 columns and 0 row

m$find('{ "val" : { "$regex" : /^a/, "$options" : "i" }  }')
# Error: Invalid JSON object: { "val" : { "$regex" : /^a/, "$options" : "i" }  }
```

Whereas in the mongo shell (I use robomongo) you **can** use either

```
db.test.find({ "val" : { "$regex" : /^a/ }  })
## or
db.test.find({ "val" : { "$regex" : "^a" }  })
```

---

Now, if you're after a bit more speed getting your data into `R`, and your result can be coerced into a `data.table` without loss of data, you can use a package I've written that extends `mongolite` that uses `data.table::rbindlist` to convert the results to a `data.table`. The speed is gained as it assumes your data is in a "tabular" structure and avoids the recursive calls in mongolite that simplifies JSON to a data.frame. See [my github page](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/mongolitedt) for more details.

```
# library(devtools)
# install_github("SymbolixAU/mongolitedt")
library(mongolitedt)
bind_mongolitedt(m)

m$finddt('{ "val" : { "$regex" : "^A", "$options" : "i" }  }')
## returns a data.table
#  Imported 5 records.
#     id val
# 1:  26   a
# 2:  53   a
# 3:  61   a
# 4:  76   a
# 5: 100   a
```

Comment: Thanks for all the details. Thanks for the pointer on `mongolitedt` library too, looks interesting

Comment: @KateK - no problem. Note that `mongolitedt` is not on CRAN, it's still in development, but should be stable enough for general use.